# Get item value in a loop with failed tasks in Ansible

Tags: loops, ansible

There is a one interesting thing I try to perform with Ansible but something goes wrong.

Example:

1. A text file contains IP addresses of some hosts.
2. I need to read each line in the file and check whether SSH port is open for every IP address.
3. If I get a timeout while checking host port then I should know what IP address seems to have a problem and pass this item into the variable to perform additional checks.

File content:

```
1.1.1.1
1.1.1.2
1.1.1.2
```

Ansible playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: Get list of IP adresses
    shell: cat /home/file
    register: ip_addrs
  - name: Check SSH port
    wait_for:
      host: "{{ item }}"
      port: 22
      timeout: 5
    with_items: "{{ ip_addrs.stdout_lines }}"
    ignore_errors: true
```

My playbook ends with results:

```
ok - 1.1.1.1
ok - 1.1.1.2
timeout - 1.1.1.3
```

The result of the loop includes results of every task in one reply.
My question: How can I extract the value of the item in a loop which caused my task to fail?

Something like `register: result` for task in a loop and some command for the item `when: result|failed`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register result of your looped task and check sub-result of each item, like this:

```
  - name: Check SSH port
    wait_for:
      host: "{{ item }}"
      port: 22
      timeout: 5
    with_items: "{{ ip_addrs.stdout_lines }}"
    ignore_errors: true
    register: loop_res
  - debug:
      msg: bad host
    when: item is failed
    with_items: "{{ loop_res.results }}"
```